# Wildfly 12 deployment fails - Required services that are not installed - StandardServletAsyncWebRequest

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly, ear

I'm porting an app from Weblogic to Wildfly 12 which - besides others- has Spring 4.2.4 dependencies. Compile is clean, but when deploying the EAR I get the following errors:

```
2018-03-16 06:47:35,258 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".START",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation\".START",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl\".START"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldEndInitService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.c\".START, jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl\".START, jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation\".START]"]
}
2018-03-16 06:47:35,273 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => [
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".START",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation\".START",
        "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl\".START"
    ],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".WeldEndInitService is missing [jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest\".START, jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl\".START, jboss.deployment.subunit.\"xxx-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.ear\".\"web-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.war\".component.\"org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider$Servlet3Continuation\".START]"]
}
```

I get no 'real' exception before this, just a warning like this:

```
2018-03-13 10:40:04,604 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-2) Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0048: Could not find default constructor for class org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.DefaultInterceptorConfigurator.configure(DefaultInterceptorConfigurator.java:92)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:92)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:144)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1714)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1693)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1540)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

As I learned from other posts here, the missing default ctor ist nothing to be alarmed of.

The EAR contains the following Jars:

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
avalon-framework-4.0.jar
axis-1.3.jar
axis-jaxrpc-1.3.jar
axis-saaj-1.3.jar
bcmail-jdk14-138.jar
bcprov-jdk14-138.jar
bsh-1.2b7.jar
byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar
cglib-nodep-2.2.2.jar
classmate-1.3.1.jar
com.springsource.javax.media.jai.codec-1.1.3.jar
com.springsource.javax.media.jai.core-1.1.3.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
commons-chain-1.1.jar
commons-codec-1.9.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-configuration-1.10.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-discovery-0.2.jar
commons-io-2.5.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-lang3-3.4.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
commons-proxy-1.0.jar
commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
core-2.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
dti2.jar
ehcache-2.10.1.jar
excalibur-collections-1.0.jar
excalibur-component-1.0.jar
excalibur-logger-1.0.jar
excalibur-pool-1.0.jar
flyway-core-4.2.0.jar
fontbox-0.1.0.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.11.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.3.4.Final.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
itext-2.0.8.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
jackson-core-2.9.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar
jackson-datatype-hibernate5-2.9.0.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
javase-2.0.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
jaxen-1.1.6.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jdom-1.1.3.jar
jempbox-0.2.0.jar
jibx-extras-1.3.1.jar
jibx-run-1.3.1.jar
joda-time-2.9.5.jar
jta-1.1.jar
junit-4.11.jar
libphonenumber-7.2.1.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
logkit-1.2.jar
oro-2.0.8.jar
pdfbox-0.7.3.jar
poi-3.13.jar
qrgen-1.3.jar
schema2java-1.1.4.jar
send2dti-1.0.jar
serializer-2.7.2.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.24.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.24.jar
snmpTrapAppender_1_2_9.jar
soap-2.3.1.jar
spring-security-crypto-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
sslext-1.2-0.jar
utils-8.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
vdbIBANConverter-20150608-1.2.4.jar
velocity-1.7.jar
velocity-tools-2.0.jar
viterra.jar
wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar
xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xpp3-1.1.3.4.O.jar
xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
xstream-1.1.3.jar
zehon_file_transfer-1.1.6.jar
```

and the WAR these:

```
ant-1.8.1.jar
ant-launcher-1.8.1.jar
antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
args4j-2.0.26.jar
asm-4.0.jar
asm-analysis-4.0.jar
asm-commons-4.0.jar
asm-tree-4.0.jar
asm-util-4.0.jar
backport-util-concurrent-3.1.jar
bcprov-jdk15on-1.51.jar
bourbon-gem-jar-2.1.0.jar
bytelist-1.0.11.jar
closure-compiler-externs-v20140814.jar
closure-compiler-v20140814.jar
coffee-script-1.8.0.jar
commons-exec-1.1.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar
dojo-shrinksafe-1.7.2.jar
emberjs-1.5.0.jar
esapi-2.0.1.jar
gmaven-feature-api-1.3.jar
gmaven-feature-support-1.3.jar
gmaven-runtime-1.7-1.3.jar
gmaven-runtime-api-1.3.jar
gmaven-runtime-support-1.3.jar
groovy-all-1.7.4.jar
gshell-io-2.0.jar
gson-2.5.jar
guava-18.0.jar
handlebars-1.3.0.jar
ical4j-1.0.7.jar
invokebinder-1.2.jar
jcodings-1.0.10.jar
jffi-1.2.7-native.jar
jffi-1.2.7.jar
jline-0.9.94.jar
jnr-constants-0.8.5.jar
jnr-enxio-0.4.jar
jnr-ffi-1.0.10.jar
jnr-netdb-1.1.2.jar
jnr-posix-3.0.3.jar
jnr-unixsocket-0.3.jar
jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
joni-2.1.1.jar
jquery-1.10.2-1.jar
jruby-core-1.7.14.jar
jruby-stdlib-1.7.14.jar
jshint-2.4.3.jar
jslint-c657984cd7.jar
json-20090211.jar
json2-20110223.jar
jsr305-1.3.9.jar
juniversalchardet-1.0.3.jar
jzlib-1.1.2.jar
less-1.3.3.jar
less4j-1.17.2.jar
livecycle-2.1.0.jar
mapstruct-1.0.0.Final.jar
nailgun-server-0.9.1.jar
nekohtml-1.9.13.jar
not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3.9.jar
ognl-3.0.8.jar
opensaml-2.6.4.jar
openws-1.5.4.jar
options-1.2.jar
plexus-utils-2.0.1.jar
prettytime-4.0.1.Final.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
qdox-1.10.jar
rhino-1.7R5-20130223-1.jar
sass-gems-3.2.1.jar
snakeyaml-1.13.jar
spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-mobile-device-1.1.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
springfox-core-2.3.1.jar
springfox-schema-2.3.1.jar
springfox-spi-2.3.1.jar
springfox-spring-web-2.3.1.jar
springfox-swagger-common-2.3.1.jar
springfox-swagger-ui-2.3.1.jar
springfox-swagger2-2.3.1.jar
struts-1.1.jar
struts-legacy-1.1.jar
swagger-annotations-1.5.5.jar
swagger-models-1.5.5.jar
thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar
thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
utils-1.07.00.jar
webjars-locator-0.19.jar
wro4j-core-1.7.7.jar
wro4j-extensions-1.7.7.jar
xmlsec-1.5.7.jar
xmltooling-1.4.4.jar
yecht-1.0.jar
```

Servlet Version is 3.1.

Sadly I cannot get around the missing optional services in the first place.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Best regards
Mark.

Edit: Thanks to the hint below I got rid of the troublesom CXF-references und the corresponding class vanished from the list of missing services. The Spring-related classed I was unable to resolve so far.

Comment: Is there an error further up the log?

Comment: no error - only the DEBUG message concerning the missing default ctor - nothing else.

Comment: What jars are being included in your EAR and WAR?  What version of the servlet spec does your web.xml have?

Comment: edited post with list of Jars.

Comment: Maybe there is a conflict the CXF provided in your WAR and the one provided by WildFly. Do you have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`? Hibernate may have a conflict as well.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what the reason for this error is, but to overcome I put in some excludes in beans.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
    <scan>
      <exclude name="org.apache.cxf.transport.http.Servlet3ContinuationProvider" />
      <exclude name="org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl" />
      <exclude name="org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest" />
    </scan>
  </beans>
```